# Changes to style.css not showing up

Tags: php, css, stylesheet

My website, pretendcity.org has a custom theme created by someone else. To edit content I use dreamweaver and go into the server to open up the individual files (ex: if I need to add something to the header, I will edit header.php).

My issue is that when I edit/update the style.css file for the website it doesn't update right away. For example I changed the background color from #353535 to #000000 and there were no changes. So I left the background color as #000000 in style.css for weeks and no changes were found on the website. Then today, WordPress had an automatic update to 3.9.2 and I found the background color suddenly changed to #000000.

Now I'm trying to change it back to #353535 and it will not make any changes.

Here is the style.css for the website:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*
Theme Name: Pretend City Children's Museum
Theme URI: http://pretendcity.org
Description: Pretend City v2
Author: Slava Popov
Author URI: http://laydbak.com
*/

/* =================
0081cd - Blue
83bc34 - Green
353535 - Text
cbcbcb - Borders
==================*/

/* =========== */
/* Page Styles */
/* =========== */

body {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #353535;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
img {border: 0;}
table {margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 0; line-height: 19px; vertical-align: top !important; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;}
td {vertical-align: top !important;}
p {line-height: 19px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color: #353535; margin-bottom: 10px;}
h1 {color: #0081cd; font-size: 24px; margin: 0 0 10px 0;}
h2 {color: #353535; font-size: 18px;}
h3 {color: #83bc34; font-size: 16px;}
h3 a {color: #83bc34;}
h4 {font-size: 14px;}
h5 {font-size: 14px;}
h6 {color: red; font-size: 11px;}
hr {
    border: none 0;
    border-top: 1px dashed #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
a {color: #0081cd; text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
ul {
    line-height: 19px;
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 0 0 20px 20px;}
.wrap {
    background: #FFF;
    border-left: #cbcbcb 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #cbcbcb 1px solid;
    border-right: #cbcbcb 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 958px;
    }
```

here is the header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>"/>
<meta property="twitter:pretendcity" content="42741399" />
<title><?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/favicon.ico" />
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/shortcode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/all-ie-only.css" /><![endif]-->
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS -->
 <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-38311913-1', 'pretendcity.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS -->
</head>

<!--[if IE 7]>  <body class="lt-ie8">   <![endif]-->

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<!-- Top Info Bar -->
<div id="infobar">
    <div>
        <span><strong>Address:</strong> 29 Hubble, Irvine, CA 92618 (<a href="https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Pretend+City+Children's+Museum,+29+Hubble,+Irvine,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Pretend&amp;sll=33.835232,-117.8461&amp;sspn=0.246678,0.528374&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Pretend+City+Children's+Museum,+29+Hubble,+Irvine,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=12592966360647214510" target="_blank" class="map">Get Directions</a>)</span>
        <span><strong>Phone:</strong> 949.428.3900</span>
        <span><strong>Hours:</strong> Tues. - Sun.. 10a.m. - 5p.m.</span>
        <span>Monday 10a.m. - 1p.m.</span>
        <strong>Ages:</strong> Infants to 8 years old
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Header & Logo -->
<header>


    <a href="/">
        <div class="logo" title="Pretend City Children's Museum"></div>
    </a>

    <!-- <a href="https://tickets.pretendcity.org/public/loader.asp?target=donation.asp?code=0013" target="_blank"> -->
    <a href="https://16116.blackbaudhosting.com/16116/General-Contributions" target="_blank">
        <div class="donate" title="Donate Today!"></div>
    </a>
<!-- Paypal Donate Button -->
      <div class="paypalicon" style="margin-top:55px; margin-left: 600px"><form title="Donate Today!" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="228Z5CXX3WVT8" />
<input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://pretendcity.org/images_home/donate-with-paypal-button-54.png" />
<img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form></div>



</header>
<!-- Main Body Wrapper -->
<div class="wrap">
    <!-- Navigation Start -->
    <nav id="menu">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'main-navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can't you log in to the wp-admin panel and edit the CSS there? It's set up that way so that you don't have to use Dreamweaver.

Comment: hard refresh, hit CTRL + F5 in your browser, you're likely seeing cached CSS. See here for ways to make it stop: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/prevent-css-caching/

Comment: i've used an ingonito window, cleared my cache, and hit CTRL + F5 and still the same..no changes seen

Answer (score 2):

The CSS file may be cashed in the browser. Try refreshing the page with CTRL+F5 (IE, FF or Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the css file, then open this site and open the linked stylesheet then check if these changes were there in the stylesheet. If you see the changes there then use the dev tools to figure out what's wrong with that changes maybe some styles would be overriding your styles. Also try `ctrl + f5` solution from the comments.

Comment: that's what i did in the past and when i checked the source code the changes i made didn't show up.